Prior to Polaris Dawn, when was the most recent non-station EVA?
Prior to the Polaris Dawn spacewalk in September 2024, when was the most recent non-station EVA?
Specifically excluding:

EVAs that occurred at the ISS or Tiangong space station
EVAs that occured from the Shuttle while the Shuttle was near to or docked at the ISS

I suspect it's probably one of the later Shuttle missions, like STS-125, but does anyone know for sure? Did the Chinese run a Gemini-type program too with free flying EVA?

Looks like Chinese did first EVA in 2008, before STS-125, and the second EVA only in 2021, from Tiangong. And nobody except ISS crews have conducted EVAs in time between.

Your supposition in the question is correct. STS-125 in 2009. The last EVA involving shuttle crewmembers was STS-134 (while docked).

It would be interesting to see a list of all non-station EVA's, seems like there weren't that many?  Voskhod and whatever else the Russians did, a few during Gemini, a few during Apollo. I think all of the Shuttle EVA's were related to satellites like Hubble, the Intelsat capture, and the free-flyer tests, or were there other Shuttle non-station EVA's that I am forgetting about?

I guess you should also exclude lunar EVAs otherwise someone is bound to eventually pop on with that as an answer. Although when you think about it the LMs were sort of used as a lunar station.

@StevePemberton there were some interesting EVAs related to testing out space station construction methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EASE/ACCESS . Probably others I'm not thinking of. Walking to Olympus is a good reference https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/walking-to-olympus_tagged.pdf

A manual check through Wikipedia's list of EVAs shows that the last non-station EVA was in 2009 during STS-125, the fifth and final servicing mission to the Hubble Space Telescope.
